# how to insert a data in PHP/MySQL from a drop down?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my form

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option>Select One</option>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

i want to insert the data from the list, insert new data, and also when i edit the information

thanks in advance

Comment: That is not your form, that is your select!

Comment: thanks for fast reply, that is the values/choices that i want to insert to the fields in my MySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put this select inside html form give some action to form

```
 <form action ="register.php" name="myform" method = "POST">
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value = "M">Male</option>
            <option value = "F">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

on your register.php file use this to get the select value

`$gender = $_POST["gender"];`  // chose whetever your form method

establish the database connection please do refer some tutorials (if you don't know )

write the mysql insert command like

```
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO yourtable (gender) VALUES ('$gender')";

        mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

now you can insert this value in your mysql or any database table

this is not tested

Comment: sorry for the innocence just new in php/mysql
please post the full codes of the action file, very much appreciated.

Comment: Ok so I insert the data to my database, but how can I display it when i'm on a edit page, keeps displaying the "Select One" not Male or Female

Comment: ask a seperate question with what you have tried and mark as correct if you satisfied with answer

Comment: sorry for that user1614526, you mean i have to post another question? just like the this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php 

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(gender) VALUES ($gender)");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[PHP MySQL: Creating Form Insert Data](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html)** and **[Processing form data with PHP](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_forms.htm)**. Useful for beginners.

For your question you may either use `$_POST["gender"]` or `$_GET["gender"]` to grab dropdown data in your php file (to where the form targets or simply the php file inside your form `action ="your_php_file.php"`) according to the `method` of your form.